# DotNetZip Exception after Upgrading to Mono 4.8 (FileNotFoundException: I18N)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mono, xamarin.mac

I just upgraded my Xamarin to the latest that includes the new Mono 4.8.

My projects are all set to Xamarin .NET 4.5.2.

I have been using Ionic DotnetZip library in this project.

I am building for OSX.

I checked out my code on a mac that has not been updated and it still works, so it is definately the upgrade in .NET or Mono that is causing the problem.

The problem is that now when I try to instanciate a ZipFile object I get a FileNotFoundException:

Could not load file or assembly 'I18N, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756' or one of its dependencies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you are including references for the `I18N`-based internationalization that you are using on your `Xamarin.Mac` application:

[image]

And in the project options, under the `Mac Build` settings, select which I1BN resource(s) to package in your app bundle:

[image]

Comment: That was it. That must be a new thing with the latest Xamarin. Thank You!!!

Comment: @user856232 Yes, new requirement for the iOS and Mac packaging when using I18N

Comment: To add the I18N assemblies, right-click References and select "Assemblies" in the dialog to add them from the Framework, for anyone else who was confused. (They are not nuget packages; they are part of the Mono framework.)